# node.js fs - stream file "backwards" - from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using Node.js, what is the best way to stream a file from a filesystem into Node.js, but reading it backwards, from bottom to top? I have a large file, and there doesn't seem to be much sense in reading from the top if I only want the last 10 lines. Is this possible?

Right now I have this horrible code, where we do a GET request with a browser to view the server logs, and pass a query string parameter to tell the server how many lines at the end of the log file we want to read:

```
function get(req, res, next) {

    var numOfLinesToRespondWith = req.query.num_lines || 10;

    var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(stderr_path, {encoding: 'utf8'});

    var jsonData = [];   //where jsonData gets populated
    var ret = [];

    fileStream.on('data', function processLineOfFileData(chunk) {
        jsonData.push(String(chunk));
    })
    .on('end', function handleEndOfFileData(err) {
        if (err) {
            log.error(colors.bgRed(err));
            res.status(500).send({"error reading from smartconnect_stdout_log": err.toString()});
        }
        else {

         for(var i = 0; i < numOfLinesToRespondWith; i++){
                ret.push(jsonData.pop());
           }

          res.status(200).send({"smartconnect_stdout_log": ret});

        }
    });
}
```

the code above reads the whole file and then adds the number of lines requested to the response after reading the whole file. This is bad, is there a better way to do this? Any recommendations will be met gladly.

(one problem with the code above is that it's writing out the last lines of the log but the lines are in reverse order...)

One potential way to do this is:

```
process.exec('tail -r ' + file_path).pipe(process.stdout);
```

but that syntax is incorrect - so my question there would be - how do I pipe the result of that command into an array in Node.js and eventually into a JSON HTTP response?

Comment: You should try to avoid asking "What is the best way..", as that typically leads to asking for opinionated answers. You likely meant to instead ask "How can i...". If you really did want to know "what was best", you need to specify the things your comparing and what would make one "better" than the other.

Comment: I don't think there's any such capability built into the pre-built streams.  So, you could create your own stream that presented lines in backwards order.  You've have to create a stream object and read the file backwards (using regular `fs.read()` calls), convert it into lines and then feed it to your stream object.  Or, if you really just want the last N lines, you can just write a non-stream function that just reads blocks from the end of the file until it has found that last N lines and then returns those lines.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I created a module called `fs-backwards-stream` that could may meet your needs. https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-backwards-stream

If you need the result parsed by lines rather than byte chunks you should use the module `fs-reverse` https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-reverse or

both of these modules stream you could simply read the last n bytes of a file.

here is an example using plain node fs apis and no dependencies.

https://gist.github.com/soldair/f250fb497ce592c3694a

hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

One easy way if you're on a linux computer would be to execute the `tac` command in node as `process.exec("tac yourfile.dat")` and pipe it to your write stream

You could also use [slice-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slice-file) and then reverse the order yourself.

Also, look at what @alexmills said in the comments

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114041/how-can-i-get-the-tac-command-on-os-x

Comment: not sure if this will stream the file, or just attempt to send all the data from the file at once in one big chunk?

Answer (score 2):

this is the best answer I got, for now

the tail command on Mac/UNIX reads files from the end and pipes to stdout (correct me if this is loose language)

```
    var cp = require('child_process');

    module.exports =  function get(req, res, next) {

        var numOfLinesToRespondWith = req.query.num_lines || 100;

        cp.exec('tail -n 5 ' + stderr_path, function(err,stdout,stderr){

            if(err){
                log.error(colors.bgRed(err));
                res.status(500).send({"error reading from smartconnect_stderr_log": err.toString()});
            }
            else{
                var data = String(stdout).split('\n');
                res.status(200).send({"stderr_log": data});
            }
        });
    }
```

this seems to work really well - it does, however, run on separate process which is expensive in it's own way, but probably better than reading an entire 10,000 line log file.

Comment: Hi, just found this and it does exactly what i want to, but what if i would add multiple OS support? I'm developing the server on OSX and deploying it on a Linux server. I googled a bit on the tail command for linux to make sure it exists, but does it work the same way as OSX? In short terms: Will this code example work on both Linux and OSX?

Comment: yeah this should be cross-platform, but you may wish to use cp.spawn or cp.fork instead of cp.exec, and you also may wish to use the  tail -F option(stands for follow) to continue stream data from the tail command.

Comment: This will obviously not work for windows. I am also looking for something like this, but using a pure javascript solution.

Comment: @ucipass can you install bash on windows? Does this need to work for many users or just you? If you install bash on windows, then I would imagine the tail command would be available.

Comment: I found [read-last-lines](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-last-lines). Looking at the code on GitHub gave me a really good idea of how to do it and the NPM module is also really fast reading line backwards for large files. It is pure JavaScript.