# How to read large jsonl file backwards in nodejs

Tags: node.js, large-files

A simple way to read files line by line top to bottom:

```
const { once } = require('events');
const { createReadStream } = require('fs');
const { createInterface } = require('readline');

let storeProducts = async () => {
    try {
        const filename = path.join(__dirname, "bulk-101638307937.jsonl");
        const rl = createInterface({
          input: createReadStream(filename),
          crlfDelay: Infinity
        });
    
        rl.on('line', (line) => {
          // Process the line.
          console.log({line: JSON.parse(line)});
        });
    
        await once(rl, 'close');
    
        console.log('File processed.');
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

this works well. But **I need to read a large jsonl file backwards line by line**. I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234228/node-js-fs-stream-file-backwards-from-bottom-to-top/32237177) .It reads file backwards but not line by line. Any help would be appreciated.

A sample jsonl

```
{"id": 1, "product": "A"}
{"variant_id": 1, "product": "A"}
{"id": 2, "product": "B"}
{"variant_id": 2, "product": "B"}
{"id": 3, "product": "C"}
{"variant_id": 3, "product": "C"}
{"id": 4, "product": "D"}
{"variant_id": 4, "product": "D"}
{"variant_id": 5, "product": "D"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The library [fs-reverse](https://github.com/dominictarr/fs-reverse) should do the trick:

```
const fsR = require('fs-reverse');
const filename = './sample.jsonl';

const readStream = fsR(filename, {})

readStream.on('data', (line) => {
  if(line) { // have this check to make sure empty lines are not parsed
    console.log(JSON.parse(line))
  }
})
```

Comment: Awesome! It is suitable to read 2GB of data, right? I don't have a large file with me right now to test.

Comment: Haven't looked at the source code in detail, but from the looks of it as it's creating a stream, yes.